# Help with installing the nvidia-96 branch in lununtu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, launchpad

Can anyone give me step-by-step directions on how to install this branch to my computer?

https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/nvidia-graphics-drivers-96/trusty

I have done `sudo bzr branch lp:ubuntu/trusty/nvidia-graphics-drivers-96` and it starts downloading 100+MB while the package is by far smaller! Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- Nothing wrong, but you need to download the whole history. You can download only last revision:

  Browse code → View revision →  Download tarball
- Well, you can always search through http://packages.ubuntu.com/.

  It was not distributed for trusty, last I could find was build for precise: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/nvidia-96 . You could try it.
- Another option, that driver is just packaging for the binary distributed by nVidia. You may download them as they are from the git repository here:

  https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/nvidia-graphics-drivers-96/trusty/files

  32bit: NVIDIA-Linux-x86-96.43.20-pkg0.run 
  64bit: NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-96.43.20-pkg2.run

  Then install it manually.